# mysql lowest and highest value with join

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables :

`mysql> SELECT * FROM master_products;
+----+-------+
| id |  name |
+----+-------+
|  1 |  row1 |
|  2 |  row2 |
|  3 |  row3 |
|  4 |  row4 |
+----+-------+`

AND

`mysql> SELECT * FROM products;
+----+---------+-------+
| id | masterid | cost |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |    1     | 1000 |
|  2 |    1     | 1050 |
|  3 |    2     | 1020 |
|  4 |    2     | 999  |
|  4 |    3     | 899  |
+----+-------+---------+`

I want to select all product from master table with highest and lowest cost from product table, but when i am using mysql min, max function then it is not returning all products, here is my query :

SELECT master_products.id,name, MIN(cost) AS LowestCost, MAX(cost) AS HighestCost 
FROM master_products 
JOIN `product` ON `product`.`masterid`= `master_products`.`id`

Is there any way to get this by single query? 
desired output :

`+----+------------+------------+--------------+
| id |    name     | LowestCost | HighestCost  |
+----+-------------+------------+--------------+
|  1 |    row1     | 1000       |    1050      |
|  2 |    row2     | 999        |    1020      |
|  3 |    row3     | 899        |    899       |
|  4 |    row4     | NA         |    NA        |
+----+-------+-----------+------+--------------+`

Comment: Try to add `GROUP BY id` at the end of your query

Comment: Sorry, but why "it is not returning all products"? In your example I see all product prices in output correct. Can you explain more - where is problem?

Comment: @VladimirGilevich That's his 'desired' output no actual ouput

Comment: My bad. Did not read well. Then there already present answer on this question - `LEFT JOIN` + `GROUP BY master_products.id` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join:

```
SELECT master_products.id, master_products.name, MIN(cost) AS LowestCost, MAX(cost) AS HighestCost 
FROM master_products 
LEFT JOIN `products` ON `products`.`masterid`= `master_products`.`id`
GROUP BY master_products.id
```

Comment: Can you help me in my question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69005703/join-two-tables-and-extract-the-lowest-price-with-multiple-conditions-multiple